# Making a method public in JavaScript. Why this syntax?

Tags: javascript, public-members

I was studying [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) code and stumbled upon this way of exposing public methods:

```
tinymce.extend(this, {
    execCommand : execCommand,
    queryCommandState : queryCommandState,
    queryCommandValue : queryCommandValue,
    addCommands : addCommands
});
```

What is the benefit of writing the above if the below code can be used instead (with fewer lines of code and less execution time required for the same task!)

```
this.execCommand = execCommand;
this.queryCommandState = queryCommandState;
this.queryCommandValue = queryCommandValue;
this.addCommands = addCommands;
```

Or even shorter, somewhere in the declaration of an object:

```
execCommand: execCommand,
queryCommandState: queryCommandState,
queryCommandValue: queryCommandValue,
addCommands: addCommands
```

Where's the catch?

Answer (score 2):

Well, one thing that jumps out at me is the first sample that you have there is the method in which the [TinyMCE expects its arguments](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.extend) for its `extend` function.

Glancing at the source of `extend`, it checks each key value pair for `undefined`, only adding them to the object if they're defined. So, there's a little bit of added functionality that can be useful when extending a class.

Comment: correct, it expects a list of objects the given object is to be extended with. This is the way they publish their private methods, but my question is why publish that way, and not a simpler one?

Comment: Thanks Demian, to me this just means that in the case of a typo in the name of the method it will take more time to identify an error. But I guess it's hard to argue with tinymce creators unless one has done a job of a similar complexity.